# ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file: D:\Android\androidSDK/system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86_64\/kernel-ranchu

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've got a couple of Android emulators in Windows Android Studio that work fine but are API 27. I've tried installing new emulators from the AVD manager but when I select them my project seems to build but the emulator never begins and the app exits.

I've run a command prompt and run:

C:\Users\sean\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>emulator -avd Pixel_4a_API_30

but it just returns:

emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file: D:\Android\androidSDK/system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86_64/kernel-ranchu

and for other emulators I've installed:

emulator: ERROR: Can't find 'Linux version ' string in kernel image file: D:\Android\androidSDK/system-images\android-30\google_apis\x86/kernel-ranchu-64

Not sure why it seems to be looking for the file ending -64 in the x86 folder, but the non -64 file in the x86_64 folder.....?

I've got the very latest Emulator (30.7.5) which other answers to this sort of question seem to suggest needs updating, so that doesn't seem to be the problem

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?